# How do I get rid of "--" line separator when using grep with context lines?

Tags: grep

I have a text file named `compare.txt` where I want to extract the single line that follows every line that contains the pattern `nmse_gain_constant`. The following command gets me close:

```
grep -A 1 nmse_gain_constant compare.txt | grep -v nmse_gain_constant
```

But this includes a separator `--` line between every line of desired text. Any easy ideas how to get rid of the `--` lines?

Example: for an input file that looks like

```
line
line
nmse_gain_constant matching line
line after first match
line
line
nmse_gain_constant another matching line
line after second match
line
nmse_gain_constant a third matching line
line after third match
```

the output is

```
line after first match
--
line after second match
--
line after third match
```

but I'd like to have just

```
line after first match
line after second match
line after third match
```

Answer (score 118):

I do this:

```
 grep ... | grep -v -- "^--$"
```

But this works too (on many, not all OS'es)!

```
grep --no-group-separator ...
```

And it doesn't spit out that "--" or even a blank line.

Comment: `grep: unrecognized option '--no-group-separator'` on Mac OS X

Comment: instead of adding additional grep just remove the `A` flag

Comment: `--no-group-separator` is not supported by all versions of `grep`

Comment: For Mac OS X, you can install the Gnu versions of various command line tools using `brew`; this includes `grep`. I believe by default it is installed as `ggrep` (Gnu Grep). This supports the `--no-group-separator` option. I have done this and it works. See this link as a reference [How to install and use GNU Grep in macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-macos#:~:text=104-,GNU,-grep%20is%20not)

Answer (score 25):

There is an undocumented parameter of grep: "--group-separator", which overrides the default "--". You can set it to "" to get rid of the double dash. Though, you still get an empty line.  I had the same trouble, and found this param by reading the source code of grep.

Comment: You can use --no-group-separator (see below)

Comment: even if I set `--group-separator=""`, the group separator is not actually empty, but still gets colored. So instead of an empty line, the separator line contains the color code, i.e `[[36m[[K[[m[[K`. Is there any way to disable coloring of the separator, while keeping grep `--color=always`?

Comment: there is no such option on mac for `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: I can confirm Tim's statement - I've got the same version of grep and it is not available.

Comment: why not just remove the `A` flag that adds this instead of additional processing.

Comment: @eddie the `A` flag was needed for the search to find what the person was looking for.  very often you're looking for "the line after something else"

Answer (score 20):

Well, the `A` switch by default will add those characters, so it's no mystery.

`man grep` states:

```
-A NUM

    Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
    contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
    option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

But you can use a simple sed to clean up the result:

```
yourgrep | sed '/^--$/d'
```

Comment: Regexp with `sed` is overkill for this task. Why not use `grep -v -- --`?

Comment: The -A doesn't just add "--" it also prints NUM extra lines After the match. Similarly -B prints NUM lines Before the match, and -C prints NUM lines of Context from around the match. The "--" gets added to separate the groups.

Comment: This answer presumes the GNU version of grep. That excerpt of the man page, for instance, does not match at least BSD grep, GNU compatible 2.6.0-FreeBSD. Nor, in this version, is the `-A` flag exclusively responsible for the inclusion of the `--` separators.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to pipe to so many greps or use other tools (for example, sed) if you use AWK:

```
awk '/nmse_gain_constant/{getline;print }' compare.txt
```

Comment: for grep -B use:
awk '/regex/{ print x; print }; { x=$0 }'

Comment: an explanation of the getline;print part of the awk command would suit this answer as most people who try to grep when they should awk are not familiar with the awk expressions used to obtain grep equivalent results

Answer (score 6):

One solution will be:

```
grep -A 1 nmse_gain_constant compare.txt | grep -v nmse_gain_constant  | grep -v "\-\-"
```

Comment: Unecessary quoting and escaping: it's simpler to use `...| grep -v -- --`