# Egrep - find 0 (zero) and ignore previous line

Tags: grep

I am trying hard to get the output as I Like.

Current Output:

```
###Server1###
2
###Server2###
0
###Server3###
     5
###Server4###
     0
```

Required Output:

```
###Server1###
2
###Server3###
     5
```

All I am looking is to grep and ignore any line and the previous line that containts 0 (zero) in any place of the line. I am using bash shell.

Comment: `awk` would be much better for this. I don't think `grep` can do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible approach:

```
$ grep -B 1 "^\s*[1-9]$" file
###Server1###
2
--
###Server3###
     5
```

To [get rid of the `group separator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840902/1983854), we can also do:

```
$ grep --no-group-separator -B 1 "^\s*[1-9]$" file
###Server1###
2
###Server3###
     5
```

#### Explanation

Instead of using `grep -v` to find the inverse, I think it is easier to look for the lines having a single digit value not being `0`. This is done with the `"^\s*[1-9]$"` expression, that allows spaces before the digit.

With `-B 1` we make it print also the line before the matched one.

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\s*\b0\b\s*/d' file
```

```
$ sed '$!N;/\s*\b0\b\s*/d' file
###Server1###
2
###Server3###
     5
```