# Perl not giving expected output

Tags: perl

I am trying to do a pattern match search for anything that has numbers for employeeID: xxxxxx and bring all entries that matches. But it doesn't seem to work as expected. And vice versa where bring all entries that doesn't have a number in the employeeID field.

My testfile

```
dn: CN=User One,OU=Disabled,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example,DC=
 com  
userAccountControl: 514  
employeeID: user1  
comment: HIRED  
sAMAccountName: user1  

dn: CN=Given-iPad01,OU=Room,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 544  
employeeID: Given-iPad01  
sAMAccountName: Given-iPad01  
lastLogonTimestamp: 130678281934843750    

dn: CN=User Two,OU=Admins,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID:: IDE2NzQwODg=  
sAMAccountName: user2  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131685330348725308    

dn: CN=Test User2,OU=2012,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example
 ,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID: testuser2  
sAMAccountName: testuser2  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131328157284117480    

dn: CN=User Three,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID: 123456  
comment: HIRED  
sAMAccountName: user3  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131679287880585713
```

My expected output was to bring all entires except the one that has employeeID: testuser, but my result came only with entry where I have employeeID: 123456.
    Below is what i was looking for

```
dn: CN=User One,OU=Disabled,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 514  
employeeID: user1  
comment: HIRED  
sAMAccountName: user1    

dn: CN=User Two,OU=Admins,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID:: IDE2NzQwODg=  
sAMAccountName: user2  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131685330348725308    

dn: CN=User Three,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID: 123456  
comment: HIRED  
sAMAccountName: user3  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131679287880585713    

dn: CN=Test User2,OU=2012,OU=People,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 512  
employeeID: testuser  
sAMAccountName: testuser  
lastLogonTimestamp: 131328157284117480    

dn: CN=Given-iPad01,OU=Rooms,DC=training,DC=example,DC=com  
userAccountControl: 544  
employeeID: Given-iPad01  
sAMAccountName: Given-iPad01  
lastLogonTimestamp: 130678281934843750
```

Below is what I tried: 
To pull that contains number anywhere on the employeeID entry
    `perl -000 -ne 'print if /employeeID: [0-9]/' testfile`

Not to pull those contains number anywhere on the employeeID entry 
    `perl -000 -ne 'print if !/employeeID: [0-9]/i' testfile`

Comment: This only finds employee numbers that start with a digit. Add a `+`: `[0-9]+` or `\d+` and a word boundary marker: `\d+\b` or newline `\d+\n`

Comment: It looks like you're pasting real employee data.  If I were you I would edit that out.  Idk where this is from but usually it's frowned upon to post real data like that on the internet.

Comment: @Robert is this what you meant? perl -000 -ne 'print if /employeeID+: [0-9]+/i' testfile

Comment: @0112 this is not a real data, my lab and even I modified the entires before I pasted..thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Records where employee ID contains a digit?

Comment: @choroba Yes correct, employeeID contains a digit, but when pulling it should pull all the attributes that is associated to it, like dn, userAccountControl, etc.

Comment: This looks like an LDIF file. Why don't you parse it as such?

Comment: The result you say you're looking for has 'testuser' and looks like the same as your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl is certainly well suited to this task, but it might be easier to:

`grep -E -B 2 -A 3 'employeeID:\s*.*[0-9]+.*' ./testfile`

The reason you don't see the expected output from this one liner is that you're telling perl to only match things that are `[0-9]`.  You need to [quantify](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) this in the expression (with `+` or `*`), as well as match non-numerical characters (e.g. `.*`).

It would be good to [read up](http://jkorpela.fi/perl/regexp.html) on how regular expressions work. Here's an environment where you can play around with this particular expression:  https://regexr.com/3o9av

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a regex that matches all entries in your file where the employee ID is a digit.  Have I misunderstood?  That expression works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Binish I notice in your expected output you now list several entries where the employee ID is non-numerical.  In your question you state that you are _"trying to do a pattern match search for anything that has numbers for employeeID: xxxxxx and bring all entries that matches."_  I think you may need to clarify a bit more before we can help you.

Comment: The reason your regex is only matching one entry is because there is only one entry where the employeeID is numerical.  (In the data you've provided here.

Comment: Yes correct to be more clear, where the employee ID contains a digit, example it can be abcd1, 123abc, aa11bb. But it should not pull any entry that has no digits example testuser or abcd===

Comment: That's a bit different.  Would you please edit your original question to clarify that?

Comment: @Binish I've updated my answer to reflect that information

Comment: it works thanks. but got a line added with -- before the line dn: CN=Given-iPad01.

Comment: If you're running Linux use the `--no-group-seperator` flag with the expression.  If you're running OS X or something else that doesn't support that flag pipe the output of the original statement to something like  `grep -v -- "^--$"`   So the final statement ends up being `grep -E -B 2 -A 3 'employeeID:\s*.*[0-9]+.*' ./testfile | grep -v -- "^--$"` . (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840902/1596460)

Comment: The one that you posted worked https://regexr.com/3o9av . Thanks so much, I used this reg expression /employeeID:\s*.*[0-9]+.*/i'

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate being marked as the answer if this helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The digit might be preceded by anything but newline. `.` matches anything but newline, `.*` means there can be 0 or more such characters. `/m` is needed to make `^` match a start of line instead of start of string.

```
perl -000 -ne 'print if /^employeeID: .*[0-9]/m' -- file
```