# How to add lines from file where match is found in another file and merge into new file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have file `IP.txt`:

```
192.168.69.100
192.168.69.141
```

I also have file `Ports.txt`:

```
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH
```

I need the 2 files merged into `Results.txt`, like so:

```
192.168.69.100
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH

192.168.69.141
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH
```

Note how there is a new line empty space after the port's banner and before the next IP.

So, to grab the `open port... on 192.168.69....` line and the line below it, then place them after the `192.168.69....` line, then finally adding a new empty line.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the IP-Addresses and for each one, use grep -A1 to print matching lines plus the one after. Something like (untested):

```
for IP in `cat IP.txt`; do
      echo $IP
      grep -A1 $IP Ports.txt
      echo
done >Results.txt
```

Comment: Missing a `done`. Unnecessary `()`. Using backticks. `echo`. Unquoted variables. Uppercase variable. And last but not least [for-in-cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash).

Comment: can someone fix this? it is not working with what i have attempted thus far

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` with `grep` and `sed`:

```
while read -r ip ; do printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$ip" $(grep -A1 "$ip" Ports.txt) | sed '/^--$/d' ; done < IP.txt
```

Output:

```
192.168.69.100
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.100 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH

192.168.69.141
open port: 21 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
220 FTP server ready
open port: 22 on IP: 192.168.69.141 with banner:
SSH-OpenSSH
```

Depending on your version of `grep` you may be able to replace the pipe to sed with the undocumented `grep` switch `--no-group-separator` or `--group-separator ""` ([How do I get rid of "--" line separator when using grep with context lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168065/how-do-i-get-rid-of-line-separator-when-using-grep-with-context-lines)).

Script details: For each IP address in the IP.txt file search (via `grep`) for the IP address in the Ports.txt file plus the line following any IP match.   Remove the contextual grouping separator (`--`) using `sed`.  Format the output using `printf`

Comment: can you explain this further please? it is not working!

Comment: Explanation added to answer per OP's request.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "...it is not working!"?

Comment: it just outputs the IPs seperated by 2 spaces